# Nginx + PHP-FPM Timeouts, almost zero load consumption?

Tags: nginx, wordpress, timeout, php-fpm

I've got a server running on a Linode with Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, Nginx 0.7.65, MySQL 5.1.41 and PHP 5.3.2 with PHP-FPM.

There is a WordPress blog on it, updated to WordPress 3.2.1 recently.

I have made no changes to the server (except updating WordPress) and while it was running fine, a couple of days ago I started having downtimes.

I tried to solve the problem, and checking the error_log I saw many timeouts and messages that seemed to be related to timeouts. The server is currently logging this kind of errors:

```
2011/07/14 10:37:35 [warn] 2539#0: *104 an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /var/lib/nginx/fastcgi/2/00/0000000002 while reading upstream, client: 217.12.16.51, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /page/2/ HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "http://www.example.com/"

2011/07/14 10:40:24 [error] 2539#0: *231 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 46.24.245.181, server: www.example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "http://www.google.es/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=example"
```

and even saw [this previous serverfault discussion](https://serverfault.com/questions/178671/nginx-php-fpm-504-gateway-time-out-error-with-almost-zero-load-on-a-test-ser) with a possible solution: to edit `/etc/php/etc/php-fpm.conf` and change

```
request_terminate_timeout=30s
```

instead of

```
;request_terminate_timeout= 0
```

The server worked for some hours, and then broke again. I edited the file again to leave it as it was, and restarted again php-fpm (`service php-fpm restart`) but no luck: the server worked for a few minutes and back to the problem over and over. The strange thing is, although the services are running, htop shows there is no CPU load (see image) and I really don't know how to solve the problem.

[image]

The config files are on pastebin

The [`php-fpm.conf` file is here](http://pastebin.com/2Mqu6hxR)

The `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` [is here](http://pastebin.com/7DHkj9CT)

The `/etc/nginx/sites-available/www.example.com` [is here](http://pastebin.com/CU0wW47D)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried instead of "upstream" -ing in nginx.conf doing something like:

```
# Pass PHP scripts to PHP-FPM
location ~* \.php$ {
   try_files       $uri /index.php;
   fastcgi_index   index.php;
   fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
   include         fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Take a look here http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2011/nginx-and-php-fpm-configuration-and-optimizing-tips-and-tricks/

Comment: Thanks for the tip adrian7, at that time the problem was solved thanks to the hosting provider tips. I will remember your point -don't know if it would work, everything is fine now-, maybe it could be useful on future situations similar to this. Regards!

Comment: What was the "hosting provider tips" ?

Comment: I'm affraid I don't remember :( In fact, that server no longer exists. Sometime ago I moved everything from there to another VPS. Sorry!

Comment: @adrian7 Your suggestion is absolutely useless, as there's no difference between `fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;` and `upstream backend { server 127.0.0.1:9000; } fastcgi_pass backend;`.

Answer (score -1):

> and restarted again php-fpm [...] the server worked for a few minutes and back to the problem over and over

### The problem is php-fpm config

But it's not the timeout. Increasing the timeout just gives php more time to process a single request - which may mask the symptoms but is not the right solution.

The php-fpm log should make the reason why the server is struggling apparent; in my experience (obviously in the absence of information this is a guess) the php-fpm log file will contain entries like this:

```
#/var/log/php5-fpm.log
[19-Oct-2014 06:25:10] NOTICE: error log file re-opened
[19-Oct-2014 17:46:56] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase
pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 1 children, there are 
1 idle, and 5 total children
...
```

If there are only a few log entries like the above, that's not much of a problem. If there are many and only minutes or seconds apart - then php-fpm has insufficient resources for the load it's being asked to cope with.

This is not uncommon because a standard dist php-fpm config file will contain something similar to this:

```
# /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
```

Which means php-fpm will **only handle a maximum of 5 requests in parallel**.

*Especially* with something like wordpress, which for a single html page hands a large number of subsequent requests (images, css, js files etc.) also to php - it is easy for a large and ever-increasing queue of requests to form such that for any given request it must first wait for the in-process and already-waiting requests to be processed first. This leads to delays (it will show up as waiting time in any browser profiling tool) and frequently leads to a large number of time outs.

Also note that a large number of 404s (requests for anything that don't exist) is an easy way to exaggerate the limitations of any server - check for and fix any 404s that the site is generating.

### How to fix it

If the problem is that php-fpm has too few server-processes running - just increase them. The numbers to use depend on the hardware of the server it is deployed upon; here's a suggestion:

```
# /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 20
pm.start_servers = 10
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 15
```

This would permit serving 20 requests in parallel - and should alleviate any problems without causing the server to struggle.

If in doubt though, there's a simple rule to follow when changing php-fpm config:

- Increase until error messages disappear (and performance is acceptable)
- Decrease if the server runs out of memory or server load is unacceptable :)

Comment: I'm affraid the system is no longer running, so I can't really tell if that change could make things work as expected. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: Hmm, not sure. The `php5-fpm.log` message you show above does not indicate server overload, just a fifth parallel request coming in. Since 5 is the max. number of child processes, other requests will then go into a backlog. 
From this, the OP's situation would result if queue items stay for 3 min in that backlog and time out. Which means, massive server overload. Which is not cured by more PHP-FPM child processes. As a rule of thumb, these should be about the same number as CPU cores on the server.

Comment: @tanius the question states "almost zero load consumption" - running out of workers is not an indicator of massive overload, only not being able to process requests faster than they come in. You only need 1 slow request and a few concurrent users/requests to run out of workers. _FPM_ workers are ordinarily configured based on the amount of _free memory_, not cpus - i.e. php processes aren't normally cpu-bound (they wait for databases, they wait for api response, they are badly written and wait for themselves... etc.). OTOH this answer is based on an assumption - just like the above comment =).

Comment: @AD7six I've read things up again and you're right. *FPM* workers are configured based on free mem, *nginx* workers are configured according to CPU core count (like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5456191/1270008)). Must've mixed things up.